Não consigo fazer o script funcionar
Tenho uma planilha onde na coluna A existem datas. Quero um script que altere o background da linha se a data da célula da coluna A for igual ou superior a data de hoje.
Pensando nisto, esbocei o seguinte código:
function formatarLinhaPorDataFilterForEach() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();

  const resposta = obterDatas(dataRange);
  const { data, datasUnicas, linhasPorData } = resposta;

  formatar(dataRange, data, datasUnicas, linhasPorData);
  return true; // Indica que a formatação foi concluída com sucesso
}

function obterDatas(dataRange) {
  // Obter datas únicas e linhas agrupadas por data
  var datasUnicas = [];
  var linhasPorData = {};
  var dataValues = dataRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 1; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
    var data = dataValues[i][0]; // Assumindo que a data está na primeira coluna
    if (!datasUnicas.includes(data)) {
      datasUnicas.push(data);
      linhasPorData[data] = [];
    }
    linhasPorData[data].push(i + 1);
  }

  return {
    data: dataValues[0][0], // Assumindo que a data está na primeira linha
    datasUnicas: datasUnicas,
    linhasPorData: linhasPorData
  };
}

function formatar(dataRange, data, datasUnicas, linhasPorData) {
  // Formatar linhas por data agrupada utilizando loop for e setBackground()
  for (var dataAtual of datasUnicas) {
    var linhas = linhasPorData[dataAtual];
    var cor = dataAtual >= new Date() ? "#c4fcbd" : null;
    for (var i = 0; i < linhas.length; i++) {
      console.log(typeof(linhas[i]));
      var rowIndex = linhas[i]; // Acesse o índice da linha no array linhas
      var row = dataRange.getRow(rowIndex);
      row.forEach(function(cell) {
        cell.setBackground(cor);
      });
    }
  }
}

Ao rodar o script, o seguinte erro aparece:
Exception: The parameters (number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.getRow.
formatar    @ Código.gs:43
formatarLinhaPorDataFilterForEach   @ Código.gs:9
Alguém consegue me ajudar?

O método getRow() recebe somente uma referência de célula da planilha, como A1 por exemplo. No seu caso, vc está enviando somente um index (exemplo: número 2).
Pra resolver isso, vc só precisa converter o index em uma referência de célula, usando o SpreadsheetApp.getRangeById(). Um exemplo abaixo:
for (var dataAtual of datasUnicas) {
var linhas = linhasPorData[dataAtual];
var cor = dataAtual >= new Date() ? "#c4fcbd" : null;
for (var i = 0; i < linhas.length; i++) {
var rowIndex = linhas[i]; // Acesse o índice da linha no array linhas
var cellRange = SpreadsheetApp.getRangeById(rowIndex); // Converte o índice da linha em uma referência de célula
cellRange.forEach(function(cell) {
cell.setBackground(cor);
});
}
}

https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8842/conte%c3%bado-gerado-por-chatgpt-e-similares-n%c3%a3o-%c3%a9-permitido-no-stack-overflow-em-por?cb=1
